# Python 3D voxel plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, voxel

I'm trying to represent a 3D voxelized geometry with a certain value for each voxel. I'm loading all values as a float64 variable "data".
First I did:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.voxels(data, facecolors=plt.cm.gist_heat_r(norm(data)), shade=True, alpha=0.75)
```

And it worked but not when voxels are of different size, this image is a voxelized geometry (299,148,348) voxels but different size:

[image: Image without scaling voxels]

So I scaled voxel values as:

```
ax.localPbAspect = scale
xmin, xmax = ( lim / ax.localPbAspect[0] for lim in ax.get_xlim3d() )
ymin, ymax = ( lim / ax.localPbAspect[1] for lim in ax.get_ylim3d() )
zmin, zmax = ( lim / ax.localPbAspect[2] for lim in ax.get_zlim3d() )
ax.auto_scale_xyz([xmin,xmax], [ymin,ymax], [zmin,zmax])
```

Where scale is the scaling relation for each axis X Y Z number in (0,1]

It does the scaling but print a huge 3D grid, and if I change the auto_scale axis values it does not scale them:
[image: Image scaling voxels]

Is there any way of obtaining this second image scaled but with a small grid axis so the voxelized picture is centered and not in a corner?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. This problem is difficult to reproduce. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly.